# Is it possible to access from a third party front end to an Angular application using an HTTP POST?

Tags: angular, http-post, integration

I have the following scenario:

- I have an `Angular` application, with a frontend exposed over Apache `httpd` and the backend on a `JBoss` server
- A third party application with its own frontend need to access to my application

They would want to access to my application using an **HTTP POST** request instead of an HTTP GET.

It is possible to do that?
I have thought the following possibility:

- My backend will expose an API REST that can accept POST method
- The backend will manage the POST request answering to the client with an **HTTP 302 Status** and the link to my frontend
- The third party client will receive the **HTTP 302 POST** response redirecting to my frontend, leaving them the burden of managing the redirect

I would like to know if my idea can be valid and if there's some alternate way to access to my frontend from the origin POST method.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is it that you want to accomplish? What does the third-party need from you?

Comment: The third party simply need to access to our application from their system, but they need to invoke our url with a POST instead of a GET

Comment: What do you mean with access to your application? You mean your backend i hope? Can't you simply expose the endpoints they need to them?

Comment: It's an integration between two frontends. Their frontend need to invoke our frontend, but they are invoking it with a POST

Comment: I think the use case is beyond me.... invoking a frontend sounds horrible.